# Why does additional driver tab not have an Nvidia driver to install?

Tags: installation, drivers, nvidia, 12.10

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.10. In the "additional driver" tab of "software source" window does not have Nvidia driver installation, it has nothing? (my computer has the geforce gt540 cuda)

Comment: Updating the system generally includes the driver name in additional drives tab. Though this method is applicable and useful, I'll recommend trying to install nvidia-current through terminal, thus making you aware of more options. However, install only if you need powerful 3D acceleration else stick to Nouveau as Nvidia driver installation tends to go wrong 90% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to install the driver from the terminal. before you install the nvidia driver make sure you have installed the linux-headers, otherwise it wont configure properley

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

then install the nvidia driver

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

this should solve your problem.